# Select * from table with where and order by clause problem

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I need to get the number of items that have a comment but I cant get this SQL statement to work for me........any advice?

```
Select count(Name) as TotalComments 
from TableName where comment <> '' 
order by ID
```

Error Message:

> Column "TableName.ID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What am I missing exactly?

Comment: What's the error message? Or is it just not returning rows? Also, what's the data type for the comment field? Is it nullable?

Comment: Column "TableName.ID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait a minute...

```
Select count(Name) as TotalComments  
from TableName where comment <> ''  
order by ID
```

You're selecting a count, so the Order By clause is pointless.  You should be getting a scalar result.  ( a single value, not a set if rows)

Is this a trick question?  It's too early for that.

Simply remove the "Order By" clause.  It's unnecessary.

Comment: David is not giving you a query to try.

Comment: That's right, @Nirmal.  Thank you..  I was repeating his query (in case he changes it after I sign off.  I've had people do that so it looks like I'm answering the wrong question.)

Comment: That's too funny!  Well, I'll vouch for your smarts.

Answer (score 0):

try this (I tried it in Sql server not in MySql)

```
SELECT     Name, COUNT(ID) AS TotalComments
FROM       TableName
WHERE     (Comment IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY TotalComments
```